# spring 3: inject a dependency from a library?

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection

I am developing a project and using 3rd party libraries. Let's say I use a library which gives me the object ExtObj. In my project I have a class MyObj, which uses ExtObj. How can I configure spring 3 to inject ExtObj in MyObj?

I tried to research the topic on the internet, but I didn't find a straight answer. I would like to use xml configuration and maybe (?) `@Autowired`, not `@EJB` or `@Inject`

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE
my guess was:

```
<bean id="myObj" value="me.MyObj">
  <property name="extObj" value=" ... ??? ...">
</bean>
```

So, I don't know what I should put into value. I guess that's where the reference to the external object goes. But spring can only reference objects that have been already defined/configured in spring. So:

```
<bean id="extObj" value="ext.lib.ExtObj">
<bean id="myObj" value="me.MyObj">
  <property name="extObj" value="extObj">
</bean>
```

Is that configuration right?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-dependency-injection-di/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define a bean for your `ExtObj` in your application context (an xml file or a @Configuration class). Eg. if `ExtObj` has a constructor taking a `String` you can define the bean this way:

```
<bean id="extObj" class="ext.lib.ExtObj">
    <constructor-arg value="SomeString"/>
</bean>
```

To define `MyObj` you can use constructor injection:

```
<bean id="myObj" class="me.MyObj">
    <constructor-arg ref="extObj"/>
</bean>
```

or setter injection:

```
<bean name="myObj" class="me.MyObj">
    <property name="extObj" ref="extObj"/>
</beans>
```

If you use setter injection then `MyObj` needs to have a setter `setExtObj`. If you use constructor injection `MyObj` needs to have a constructor taking an instance of the `ExtObj` class.

Comment: +1 - This explains it.  Spring has to create both the external object and yours in order to wire them together.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can inject a 3rd party library, as long as it has constructors that Spring can access.

You can use either XML or annotations - your choice.

You need to ask Spring to instantiate the instance(s) of the library class and then inject that into your objects that need them.

You do this every time you create a Spring data source that uses a JDBC driver.  That's a 3rd party library.

Comment: Maybe my question is actually - do I have to define external Objects in some spring xml config file?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but if you want your objects to be injected with 3rd party objects you have to give Spring control and tell it how to create them for you.